# Как поменять язык в NgxMatDaterangePicker в angular?

Tags: angular

как поменять на русский язык в matDateRangePicker ?
вот мой компонент:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgxDrpOptions, PresetItem, Range } from 'ngx-mat-daterange-picker';

    @Component({
      selector: 'range-date',
      templateUrl: './range-date.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./range-date.component.scss']
    })
    export class RangeDateComponent {  
      @ViewChild('dateRangePicker') dateRangePicker;
      @Output() filteredEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();
      range: Range = { fromDate: new Date(), toDate: new Date() };
      options: NgxDrpOptions;
      presets: Array<PresetItem> = [];
      constructor() {
        const today = new Date();
        const fromMin = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 2, 1);
        const fromMax = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);
        const toMin = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 1);
        const toMax = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 2, 0);

        this.setupPresets();
        this.options = {
          presets: this.presets,
          format: 'mediumDate',
          range: { fromDate: today, toDate: today },
          applyLabel: 'Ok',
          cancelLabel: 'Выход',
          locale: 'ru-RU',
          startDatePrefix: 'Начало',
          endDatePrefix: 'Конец',
          animation: true,
          calendarOverlayConfig: {
            shouldCloseOnBackdropClick: true
          }
        };
      }
      updateRange(range: Range) {
        this.range = range;
        this.filterGridRangeDate();
      }
      filterGridRangeDate() {
        this.filteredEmitter.emit({
          fromDate: this.range.fromDate,
          toDate: this.range.toDate
        });
      }
      setupPresets() {

        const backDate = (numOfDays) => {
          const today = new Date();
          return new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - numOfDays));
        };
        const today = new Date();
        const yesterday = backDate(1);
        const minus7 = backDate(7);
        const minus30 = backDate(30);
        const currMonthStart = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
        const currMonthEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);
        const lastMonthStart = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 1);
        const lastMonthEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 0);

        this.presets = [
          { presetLabel: "Вчера", range: { fromDate: yesterday, toDate: today } },
          { presetLabel: "Последние 7 дней", range: { fromDate: minus7, toDate: today } },
          { presetLabel: "Последние 30 дней", range: { fromDate: minus30, toDate: today } },
          { presetLabel: "Этот месяц", range: { fromDate: currMonthStart, toDate: currMonthEnd } },
          { presetLabel: "Следующий месяц", range: { fromDate: lastMonthStart, toDate: lastMonthEnd } }
        ];
      }
    }
```

вот мой html:

```
<ngx-mat-drp (selectedDateRangeChanged)="updateRange($event)"
[options]="options" #dateRangePicker></ngx-mat-drp>
```

мой модуль:

```
import {NgxMatDrpModule} from 'ngx-mat-daterange-picker';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {RangeDateComponent} from './range-date.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
import {MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    NgxMatDrpModule
  ],
  declarations: [RangeDateComponent],
  exports: [RangeDateComponent],
  entryComponents: [ RangeDateComponent ],
  providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'ru-RU' }]
})
export class RangeDateModule { }
```

в итоге получаю такую штуку:
[image: mat date range picker]

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему так: `format: "dd.mm.yy"`